# How do I design this custom switch in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, switch-statement

[image]

I have to implement this custom switch design

I used `CupertinoSwitch` for the first one

and I am not sure how to design the `in-active` switch design using `CupertinoSwitch`

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CupertinoSwitch` doesn't have a lot of style parameters.

If you want a customized switch, I recommend you to use an external package like [flutter_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_switch).

You can easily add padding, change size, change color...

The README example here :

```
FlutterSwitch(
    width: 125.0,
    height: 55.0,
    valueFontSize: 25.0,
    toggleSize: 45.0,
    value: status,
    borderRadius: 30.0,
    padding: 8.0,
    showOnOff: true,
    onToggle: (val) {
       setState(() {
          status = val;
       });
    },
),
```

To get a different toggle size in function of `status`, just write :

```
toggleSize: status ? 45.0 : 25.0,
```

Comment: Yes I've tried but couldn't reduce the size of the thumb icon in inactive state of switch

Comment: To get a a different toggle size in function of status, just set `toggleSize` parameters with condition. I add an example on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `material3` property set to `true` in your themedata:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



void main() => runApp(const SwitchApp());

class SwitchApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SwitchApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Switch Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: SwitchExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SwitchExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<SwitchExample> createState() => _SwitchExampleState();
}

class _SwitchExampleState extends State<SwitchExample> {
  bool light = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Switch(
      // This bool value toggles the switch.
      value: light,
      activeColor: Colors.red,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        // This is called when the user toggles the switch.
        setState(() {
          light = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

output: [image]
[image]

more examples here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Switch-class.html